# Because A is true, so B must also be true

Tags: logic, fallacies

What is the technical term for the logical fallacy which can be stated: **"A is true, so B must also be true"** when A and B are unrelated (i.e. A does not imply B).

A very crude example could be "because 2+2 is 4... I can fly". Here both statements are irrelevant to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Non sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic)).

> Non sequitur (Latin for "it does not follow"), in formal logic, is an argument in which its conclusion does not follow from its premises.